# What program can I use on Ubuntu 20.04 Server to edit html and php?

Tags: webserver

I just rented a cloud server for my little homework website.

I have Ubuntu 20.04 Server as the cloud server.

I am used to shared web-hosting. Usually, you get cPanel or Plesk.

What is the best way to edit files on the server?

I always test my webpages and php on this laptop first, but sometimes, there is still something that needs tweaking.

On my laptop, I always use Bluefish. Is that possible, server-side??

Comment: The two text editors that ship with Ubuntu Server are `nano` and `vi`. Many people have strong opinions about which is “better”, but you’ll probably want to try both and make your own decision: `nano /var/www/html/index.html` and `vi  /var/www/html/index.html`. Be sure to think about file permissions, otherwise these editors will warn you about the files being read only 

Comment: Following advice from a website, I made www-data the owner of the files in public_html. As I have sudo powers, I can use nano to edit files, but that is not so nice. A proper code editor is preferable, for me.

Comment: aptans, eclipe if you want 2 popular ones.

Answer (score 1):

Accorging to the manual, Bluefish has ability to edit remote files:

https://bfwiki.tellefsen.net/index.php/Man_1_ch05s12#12.1._Remote_files

If you need something working in terminal, try Midnight Commander

```
sudo apt install mc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can ssh into the new cloud server no trouble, so I will look into using Bluefish!

Comment: There is nothing which asks for a password. I end up with the index.html which I get if I try and open my cloud webserver using the ip address. I have not yet linked my domain name to this new ip. I need my old webpage for the coming week.